# polar co ordinates integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, polar-coordinates, dirac-delta

integrate the polar co ordinates
$$ \int^{r=\infty}_{r=0} \int^{z=\infty}_{z=-\infty} \delta(r)  \delta(z-z_s) dz dr$$
=>
 I want to integrate the above equation.

integral of $ \int^ {z=\infty} _ {z= -\infty}   \delta(z-z_s) dz =1$
and 
integral of $ \int ^{r= ∞}_ {r=0} \delta(r) dr= \dfrac{1}{2}.$

then from the above integrations can i say

integral of
$$\int ^{r= ∞}_ {r=0} \int^ {z=\infty} _{ z= -\infty} {\delta(r)  \delta(z-z_s)} dz dr =\frac {1}{2}$$

if i integrate in terms $r$ and $z$ with respect to $\delta$ function.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you define your step function. If its defined to be $1/2$ when $r=0$ then everything looks good

Comment: $\displaystyle\large\int_{0}^{\infty}\delta\left(r\right)\,{\rm d}r$ is not defined. For example, $\displaystyle\large\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{-}}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\delta\left(r\right)\,{\rm d}r = 1$ and $\displaystyle\large\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\delta\left(r\right)\,{\rm d}r = 0$.